# UIAlertView with multiple lines of text

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter, uialertview, twtrcomposer

Because TWTRComposer does not support adding video, I have to use their RESTAPI to upload a video and create a custom interface for adding the message to a Tweet.

I wanted to do it in UIAlertView, but it seems like you cannot add multiple lines of text to a textField:
[image]

Any suggestions for how to customize a UIAlertView for multi-line text?  I'd like it to look as close as possible to the TWTRComposer window.
[image]

Comment: use textview instead of text field or create your own custom view for alert!

Comment: You can't customize `UIAlertView` (or now `UIAlertViewController`), it's specified in the doc. Use your own components. If you don't know where to start, there is plenty of samples on GitHub/CocoaControls/CocoaPods. Use a `UITextView` instead of a `UITextField`, which is suited for multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

To have multiple line text or formatted text for eg. message with bold text, you need to use attributed String. Please have a look for the same below  ---

let alertController = Utils.showAlert(Defines.APP_TITLE, message: "", handler: nil)
        let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: alertMSg, attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Avenir-Light", size: 15)!])
        alertController.setValue(attributedString , forKey: "attributedMessage")
        present(alertController, animated: true)